# Programmatically install VSTO add-ins

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I´ve developed several VSTO add-ins for MS Office 2010. I need a way to register them from a C# program.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is not what I want to do, because I need to install multiple Add-Ins at once from an Application installer.

Comment: Then add it as answer ;) Is it possible to run those installers in background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Deploying a Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff937654(v=msdn.10))

[Deploying your VSTO Add-In to All Users (via  HKLM)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx)

Comment: Worth noting that rather than following the advice in the second link, an add-in can be deployed to all users by adding a key under Office/12.0/Common/General called EnableLocalMachineVSTO and set it to 1. Then any VSTO add-in installed under HKLM will load for all users in Office 2007 products.

Answer (score 3):

To this registry key - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins add your own RegistryKey with these values: (use Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey class)
Description (string)
FriendlyName (string)
Manifest (string)
LoadBehavior (DWORD)

Manifest is absolute path to your VSTO addin + "|vstolocal" (for example: C:/myaddin.vsto|vstolocal)

LoadBehavior should be 3 - means: load at startup

FriendlyName and Description will be displayed in Word

But before first run of your addin you should execute your .vsto file (Notice that [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20479) must be installed)

```
Process.Start("C:/myaddin.vsto");
```

Comment: Here's a new link to the VSTO runtime download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56961